# Composer Update failed to execute git diff : error: bad index file sha1 signature

Tags: 8, updating, composer

When trying to update drupal 8.4.0 to 8.4.4 I get an error with composer :

```
composer update --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 3 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating behat/mink dev-master (9ea1ceb => 04ab7af):     Update failed (Failed to execute git diff --name-status composer/master...master --

error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing behat/mink (dev-master)


  [RuntimeException]                                                    
  Failed to execute git diff --name-status composer/master...master --  

  error: bad index file sha1 signature                                  
  fatal: index file corrupt
```

What can I do to solve this issue ?

Here is my composer.json file :

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.6",
    "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.3",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.20",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.3",
    "drupal/animations": "^1.2",
    "drupal/block_class": "1.x-dev",                                                                            
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.0",                                                                                  
    "drupal/twig_field_value": "^1.1",                                                                          
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^1.9",                                                                                
    "drupal/devel": "^1.2",                                                                                     
    "drupal/coffee": "1.x-dev",                                                                                 
    "drupal/form_placeholder": "1.x-dev",                                                                       
    "drupal/address": "^1.3",                                                                                   
    "drupal/prepopulate": "2.x-dev",                                                                            
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^2.2",                                                                                 
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "1.x-dev",                                                                             
    "drupal/rules": "3.x-dev",                                                                                  
    "drupal/mimemail": "1.x-dev",                                                                               
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "4.x-dev",                                                                         
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.2",                                                                          
    "drupal/google_analytics_reports": "3.x-dev",
    "drush/drush": "^8.1",
    "drupal/codesnippet": "^1.6",
    "drupal/cookieconsent": "^1.3"
},
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.4"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
        "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
        "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
        "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
    ],
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    "drupal": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try to remove vendor dir and run `composer install`.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, but then I get (trying to run composer update) : `[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]                      
  The contents of https://packagist.org/p/provider-latest%240cbfb40ab72  
  a881d21b70f78286d39cd72e3b0eb8704c13e79dc49624e549973.json do not mat  
  ch its signature. This could indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try  
   running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.`

Comment: Will be much easier to tell you if I can see your composer.json file.

Comment: Just added to the post.